# PHP problems with SQLite call to undefined function sqlite_open()

Tags: php, sqlite

i have this server in php that worked perfectly until a few days ago.

```
<?php

ini_set(‘track_errors’, ’1′) ;
$dbFile = realpath('./').'/notificheDB';
echo "work";
$dbLink=sqlite_open($dbFile, 0666, $sqliteError);
echo "omg";
if(!is_resource($dbLink)){

  $sqliteError= "Si è verificato un errore al momento dell’apertura/creazione del database <br> \n";
  $sqliteError.= '<strong>'.$php_errormsg.'</strong>' ;

  $php_errormsg="" ;

  die($sqliteError) ;

}
```

now when i use the instruction `$dbLink=sqlite_open($dbFile, 0666, $sqliteError);`the server crash but it responds with page 200.
I put the two echo to be sure of the point where it stops working, in this case the response page print to video only "work" and never "omg".

I entered manually in php.ini sqlite

```
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=sqlite.so
```

nothing the same, you have any suggestions?

thx

Comment: check `$sqliteError` variable

Comment: @viakondratiuk is empty

Comment: Can you restart your machine then try it again

Comment: @Vineet1982 I did the restart of the machine is both web service more than once. nothing to do. it never hurts to try again

Comment: @Vineet1982 Nothing to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved:

```
sudo port install php5-sqlite
```

port installs the sqlite library, restart the server and everything should work